# C++ library for decoding MKV video (Dolby Digital / AVC)

Tags: c++, ios, mkv, dolby

Before you say it: i **know** that audio decoding of Dolby Digital audio is not suitable for the market for free due to license limitations. But I only want to decode MKV video on my iPhone for study purposes.

Which libraries should I use for the audio and video? It's important to get the channels of the 5.1 audio separated.

Answer (score 0):

Ffmpeg (https://ffmpeg.org) should do it. Ffmpeg should build on iOS.

Comment: Thank you! I will check it!